# Continuing after integrating in a differential equation problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have this problem below:

$dy/dx=x^2/y^2$

With what I have

$1/x^2=1/y^2$

$ \int\  1/x^2 dx= \int\ 1/y^2 dy$

how do you continue?

Answer (score 3):

$\int\  1/x^2 dx= \int\ 1/y^2 dy$ is wrong. From $dy/dx=x^2/y^2$ you get $\int\  x^2 dx= \int\ y^2 dy$, hence $y^3=x^3+C$.

Can you proceed ?

Comment: Ok then. My book just says that I have to use the formula $ \int\ 1/g(y) dy = \int\ h(x) dx$ for this type of differential equations: $dy/dx = h(x)g(y)$. I therefore guessed that this applied for differential equations such as $dy/dx = h(x)/g(y)$ as well. However, I guess I was wrong then. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Your book is right
$$\frac {dy}{dx} = h(x)g(y)$$ 
$$\int \frac {dy}{g(y)} = \int h(x)dx$$ 
But for
$$ \frac {dy}{dx} =\frac { h(x)}{g(y)}$$
We have
$$ \int {g(y)} dy =\int { h(x)}{dx}$$
You can also apply the rule of the book on this
$$ \frac {dy}{dx} =\frac { h(x)}{s(y)}$$
Apply the rule's book with $g(y)=\frac 1 {s(y)}$
$$\frac {dy}{dx} = h(x)g(y) \to \int \frac {dy}{g(y)} = \int h(x)dx$$ 
$$ \frac {dy}{dx} =\frac { h(x)}{s(y)} \to \int \frac {dy}{\frac 1 {s(y)}} = \int h(x)dx $$
$$\int \frac {dy}{\frac 1 {s(y)}} = \int h(x)dx \to \int {s(y)} dy = \int h(x)dx $$
It gives the same answer ...